# Extjs binding another store to grid as another property

Tags: extjs, grid, bind, store

I have a grid with a store. In the ViewModel i have created the store in the **stores** property. In the grid I put the **bind** property to that store. This works well.
I want to attach another store as a property called **fullStore**. What are the steps that I should follow? It should be under **data** property or under **stores** property? Should I extend the grid component to add **fullStore** as a config?

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/34bb). I wanna use **fullStore** in the **getOptionsFromStore()** function (to populate list columns) instead of using grid store. That's because grid store is paginated.

Note: I'm using 6.5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define the configuration for the second store in the same viewmodel and bind it using the viewmodel itself [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/34b5&view/editor)(fork another fiddle for create example for you to save time). If your second storage has the same model and you do not need to display additional information, you do not need to change the component (extension from the old one)

Edit:

Ow, you continue the experiment with the grid.filter. The easiest way to do what you need is to define the store for filters themselves. But in this case, the filtering of filter store logic will stop working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/344s&view/editor). By the way, grid.filter cannot bind store(or something else), since they are not extended from `Ext.Component`, and as a result does not have `Ext.mixin.Bindable`

Comment: I think i don't explained myself well. I have updated my question with a fiddle. Please check it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to @pvlt's answer, if your model is different and you want to populate same grid with the different store, model and columns you can use [grid.reconfigure](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) method

Comment: @pvlt I want to attach a new store to the grid as a property called **fullStore**, then, when I am in the **getOptionsFromStore()** function, I want to use that store with:
    `getOptionsFromStore: function (store) {
        store = this.grid.fullStore;`
I want to do this way because I don't want to build several stores (one per column) and I want ExtJS do the process of create filters. Then I capture the filterchange event to filter the **fullStore** store.